# Enable and disable button using javascript and asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am checking if user exists in database if exists I am showing message as "existed user" and then I need to disable the signup button if not I need to enable it.

I am unable to enable and disable the sign Up button.

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $("#<% =btnavailable.ClientID %>").click(function () {
             if ($("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
                 $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").removeClass().addClass('notavailablecss').text('Required field cannot be blank').fadeIn("slow");

             } else {
                 $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn("slow");
                 $.post("LoginHandler.ashx", { uname: $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").val() }, function (result) {
                     if (result == "1") {
                         $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").addClass('notavailablecss').fadeTo(900, 1);
                       document.getElementById(#<% =btnSignUp.ClientID %>').enabled = false;
                     }
                     else if (result == "0") {
                         $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").addClass('availablecss').fadeTo(900, 1);
                        document.getElementById('#<% =btnSignUp.ClientID %>').enabled = true;
                     }
                     else {
                         $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").addClass('notavailablecss').fadeTo(900, 1);
                     }
                 });
             }
         });

         $("#<% =btnavailable.ClientID %>").ajaxError(function (event, request, settings, error) {
             alert("Error requesting page " + settings.url + " Error:" + error);
         });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: And your problem is? How can someone help you now?

Comment: My problem is unable to disable and enable the signup button.If username existed I need to disable it and if not I need to enable it.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately your problem is something as small as the difference between `enabled` and `disabled`

`.enabled = true;`

Should be :

`.disabled = false;`

Comment: Yes I have done that as shown above but when the user is available and I click SignUp button it's refreshing the page.

Comment: I see you're using `POST` so i assume you're just missing `event.preventDefault()` in your event handler on your button.

Comment: add your submit click handler to your original post.

Answer (score 10):

You can play with this:

```
$('#ButtonId').prop("disabled", true); ->> disabled
$('#ButtonId').prop("disabled", false); ->> Enabled
```

Comment: as much as i love jquery too, i dont think OP is using it.

Comment: sorry, habit of looking at the tags at a glance ;)

Answer (score 9):

Try this...

```
document.getElementById('<%= button.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('<%= button.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
```

Comment: Yeh I have tried the same thing as mentioned in the above code but not working.

Comment: I tried setting a "var" to this value and then setting the "disabled", but nothing happened. When I used the above code it all worked. I believe it has something to do with a "var" variable not being understood as a button, where the above code is still understood that way.

Answer (score 7):

**JavaScript:**

```
 function Enable() {
      $("#btnSave").attr('disabled', false);                
    }
 function Disable() {
       $("#btnSave").attr('disabled', true);
    }
```

**ASPX Page:**

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Save" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate('Validation')){javascript:Disable();}" ValidationGroup="Validation"/>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "Disable", "javascript:Disable();", True)
```

Answer (score 2):

u can just set visibility of your button to false visibility="false"

Comment: Yes I have done that too but when the user clicks the show availability then if the user exists in the database then I need to make the signUp button enabled which is not happenning

Comment: for that u have to use some if else statement with some conditions     and in c# code buttoneName.visibility=true or false

Answer (score 1):

The .disabled does work, have you used break point to make sure your code was even being reached ? Your conditional if / else's may not be returning your expected values.

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

Disable:

```
    var myButton = document.getElementById('<%= this.myButton.ClientID %>');
    $(myButton).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Enable:

```
    $(myButton).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable and disable the buttons using JavaScript, this is what should be done-

Example:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="a(); return false;"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="b(); return false;" />
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function a() {
       alert('1');
       document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
       document.getElementById('<%=Button2.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
      }
   function b() {
       alert('2');
       document.getElementById('<%=Button2.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
       document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
      }
 </script>
```

**NOTE:** While other posts had similar code, they fail because of the reload on the page. So to avoid the reload a `return false` should be added like `OnClientClick="a(); return false;"`

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript code should work.

```
document.getElementById("<%=btnSignUp.ClientID%>").disabled = true; //To disable the button

document.getElementById("<%=btnSignUp.ClientID%>").disabled = false;//To enable the button
```

Your code should look like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $("#<% =btnavailable.ClientID %>").click(function () {
             if ($("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
                 $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").removeClass().addClass('notavailablecss').text('Required field cannot be blank').fadeIn("slow");

             } else {
                 $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn("slow");
                 $.post("LoginHandler.ashx", { uname: $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").val() }, function (result) {
                     if (result == "1") {
                         $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").addClass('notavailablecss').fadeTo(900, 1);
                       document.getElementById("<%=btnSignUp.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
                     }
                     else if (result == "0") {
                         $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").addClass('availablecss').fadeTo(900, 1);
                        document.getElementById("<%=btnSignUp.ClientID%>").disabled = false;
                     }
                     else {
                         $("#<% =txtUserName.ClientID %>").addClass('notavailablecss').fadeTo(900, 1);
                     }
                 });
             }
         });

         $("#<% =btnavailable.ClientID %>").ajaxError(function (event, request, settings, error) {
             alert("Error requesting page " + settings.url + " Error:" + error);
         });
     });
</script>
```